# Background Image Style is not working in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux, rxjs

idk why background image style is not working on  react,

```
{
  musics && musics.map((name, i) => {
    console.log(typeof name.imageURL);
    return(
      <Fragment key = {i}>
        <div className = "music-preview-box">
          <div className = "user-musics-content">
            <div id = "album-cover" style ={{backgroundImage: "url("+name.imageURL+")"}}>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

when i console log it shows the url, when i put the real url instead of `name.imageURL` it works. but when i only keep `name.imageURL` it doesnt work

Comment: Could you add some more context or screenshots from debugging? Otherwise it's just guesswork...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to double quotes the url("...")

```js
<div id = "album-cover" style={{ backgroundImage:`url("${name.imageURL}")` }}></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What about -

```
 <div id = "album-cover" style ={ { backgroundImage: "url('+name.imageURL+')" } }>
```

or

```
 <div id = "album-cover" style ={ { backgroundImage: `url("${name.imageURL}")` } }>
```